# How to print 86420 in loop assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

How to print 
**86420**
use a loop assembly

I could print 02468

```
.model small
.org 100 h
.data 
.code
main proc 
mov dl,8
mov ah,2
mov cx,5
mov XX,48
top:
mov ah,2
int 21h
Add dx,2
Loop top

Mov ah,4ch
int 21h

endp
```

I tried to search a lot and could not find the right solution

Comment: Count down from `'8'` (the ASCII code for `8`) instead of up from `'0'`, obviously.  Your current loop looks broken, like it will output ASCII codes `8` to `16`, not the ASCII code for the digit.  (http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02)

Comment: What is `mov XX,48` supposed to do? I don't see `XX` being declared anywhere in your code.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

The desired output "86420" contains *descending* characters. Why then do you **add some value** in the loop?

To output characters you need to specify characters. `mov dl, 8` is not the same as `mov dl, '8'`.
An instruction like `mov dl, '8'` would be the same as `mov dl, 56` (8+48).

Now try this code:

```
 mov  dl, '8'
 mov  cx, 5
top:
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  21h
 sub  dl, 2
 loop top
```